# Change ASN.1 tag type in CSR generated by Windows 2012 Active Directory Certificate Services

Tags: windows, active-directory, openssl

I'm trying, using **OpenSSL 1.0.1e** on Debian, to sign a Certificate Signing Request coming from a initial setup of a subordinate CA under **Windows 2012 Active Directory Certificate Services (ADCS)**. My problem is that ADCS encode string items of the CSR using "**PRINTABLESTRING**" format.

I want to change the format used by ADCS from "**PRINTABLESTRING**" to "**UTF8STRING**" because OpenSSL do not recognize the equality of the string items and then reject the CSR (I use a match policy settings for attributes comparison).

I cannot find any option the change the format. Is this change is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found [interesting information](http://mikeberggren.com/post/30483904170/utf8-to-printablestring) about this point:

1. Open the original CSR and copy the base64 data between the "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----" markers.
2. Put this data into a base64 decoder and save the output as a binary file. There are a variety of online services that can do this or if you prefer there are local tools as well.
3. Download/install a hex editor. Use it to open the decoded binary file.
4. Look for two values right before the countryName: 0C 02
5. Edit the value 0C (UTF8String) and change it to 13 (Printablestring)
6. Save the changes and use a base64 encoder to encode it back to base64.
7. Add the base64 data back in between the "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----" markers.

Comment: righettod - you might want to copy the relevant text here. That will save you from being persecuted for a link-only answer; and it will ensure the text is available after the blog disappears or the webmaster re-arranges the site. And if that's the best correct answer, you might as well accept it so others know when they arrive at your question.

Comment: Please note that modifying certificate request this way will invalidate its signature and because of that it will be rejected by most of the commercial CAs. However if you sign it (issue certificate) locally with OpenSSL it will just display warning that "Signature did not match the certificate request".

Comment: Hello, Thanks you very much for the question refactoring and your answer. Sorry for my initial mistake about posting a link.